# How can one further characterise marginal couplings?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

One characterises fixed points of $\beta$-functions by the eigenvalues of the stability matrix. If one has now marginal couplings (Eigenvalues=0) one can further characterise the couplings as marginal relevant or marginal irrelevant depending on the IR behaviour. My question is now how can one compute if a marginal coupling is marginal relevant or marginal irrelevant.

Comment: That's what the sign of the beta function is telling you. More precisely, eigenvalues of $\partial \beta^i / \partial g^j$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan but as far as I know this allows one only to distinguish between marginal, relevant and irrelevant couplings.

Comment: The number of loops you have to use in order to find out if a coupling is (ir)relevant defines how marginal that (ir)relevance is.

Comment: @ConnorBehan oh sorry my question is referring to non-perturbative methods such as the FRG.

Comment: Then I don't think marginally relevant or marginally irrelevant are meaningful terms anymore.

Comment: @ConnorBehan can you pls elaborate why you think that?

Comment: Isn't this whole "marginally whatever" business just perturbative by definition? I guess you could say it applies in cases where a perturbative treatment exists even if you don't make use of it. I.e. marginal at zero coupling and relevant at finite coupling implies marginally relevant.

Comment: @ConnorBehan why should it be perturbative by definition? The notions or relevant /irrelevant/marginal directions are coming from the linearisation of the stability matrix. And if the linearisation is zero the next thing would be to look at the second derivatives of the stability matrix in order to classify the fixed points.